# Why am i unable to ajax update Primefaces ContextMenu (for DataTable)?

Tags: ajax, primefaces, contextmenu

Hi I seem unable to ajax update Primefaces ContextMenu (for Datatable) to determine whether it is active or not (based on backing bean requestBean.editMode) - is there some reason why this wont work?

```
setEditMode(Boolean.FALSE);
PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update("stContext:stctxt");


<h:form id="stContext">
    <p:outputPanel id="stctxt">
        <p:contextMenu id="ctxST" for="slotDetailForm:addSlot" rendered="#{requestBean.editMode}">
             <p:menuitem value="Edit Slot Type Details" update="SlotTypeDetailsForm:enterSlotTypeDetails" icon="ui-icon-pencil"
                actionListener="#{requestBean.editST}" 
                oncomplete="PF('enterSTypeWithDuration').show()"/>
        </p:contextMenu>

    </p:outputPanel>
</h:form>
```

I also tried moving the rendered attribute to the outputPanel with the same non-effect.
Many thanks for all relevant suggestions received!

Primefaces version 6.2

Comment: You should look in the network transfer of your browser whether the stctxt is sent at all. I had the same problem with a confirm-dialog. A confirm dialog is not updateable. Possibly a context menu, too.

Comment: Thanks Holger, i will look to see if that throws some light on the issue.

Comment: So it works if you replace the contextmenu for another component?

Comment: And can you really not update its contents or just not enable (render) it whem it was not rendered amd vice versa